# How to remove white spaces and \n in the JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have JSON data coming to S3 in the format:

```
{\n  \"data\": {\n    \"event_type\": \"message.received\",\n    \"id\": \"819\",\n    \"occurred_at\": \"2020-10\",\n    \"payload\": {\n      \"cc\": [],\n      \"completed_at\": null,\n      \"cost\": null,\n      \"direction\": \"inbound\",\n      \"encoding\": \"GSM-7\",\n      \"errors\": [],\n      \"from\": {\n        \"carrier\": \"Verizon\",\n        \"line_type\": \"Wireless\",\n        \"phone_number\": \"+111111111\"\n      },\n      \"id\": \"e8e0d1e3-dce3-\",\n      \"media\": [],\n      \"messaging_profile_id\": \"400176\",\n      \"organization_id\": \"717d556f-ba4f-\",\n      \"parts\": 1,\n      \"received_at\": \"2020-1\",\n      \"record_type\": \"message\",\n      \"sent_at\": null,\n      \"tags\": [],\n      \"text\": \"Hi \",\n      \"to\": [\n        {\n          \"carrier\": \"carr\",\n          \"line_type\": \"Wireless\",\n          \"phone_number\": \"+111111111\",\n}\n}"
```

I want it to be converted like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "event_type": "message.received",
    "id": "76a60230",
    "occurred_at": "2020-12-1",
    "payload": {
      "cc": [],
      "completed_at": null,
      "cost": null,
      "direction": "inbound",
      "encoding": "GSM-7",
      "errors": [],
      "from": {
        "carrier": "Verizon",
        "line_type": "Wireless",
        "phone_number": "+1111111111"
      },
      "id": "06c9c765",
      "media": [],
      "messaging_profile_id": "40017",
      "organization_id": "717d5",
      "parts": 1,
      "received_at": "2020-1",
      "record_type": "message",
      "sent_at": null,
      "tags": [],
      "text": "Hi",
      "to": [
        {
          "carrier": "abc",
          "line_type": "Wireless",
          "phone_number": "+1111111111",
          "status": "delivered"
        }
      ],
      "type": "SMS",
      "valid_until": null,
      "failover_url": null,
      "url": "https://639hpj"
    },
    "record_type": "event"
  },
  "meta": {
    "attempt": 1,
    "delivered_to": "https://639hpj"
  }
}
```

The first JSON data I kept came in lines and not in the Struct format. I did not keep the actual JSON data but it was in that similar format (but valid). I would like to run a lambda function in which the JSON data is free from `\n` and white spaces.

The above 2 JSON data are not the same but I will be receiving the first type of JSON data and I would like to convert it to the second type which is free of white spaces and `\n`.

Comment: If you do `print(my_variable)` instead of typing `my_variable` at the `>>>` prompt it will appear the way you want. The difference is that you are looking at the variable in Python's default representation, which is the source code you need to re-create the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you realize that spaces and newlines are what `print` uses for formatting?

Lets us call `t` your first json (I fixed it by adding the missing brackets at the end):

```
t = '''{\n "data": {\n "event_type": "message.received",\n "id": "819",\n "occurred_at": "2020-10",\n "payload": {\n "cc": [],\n "completed_at": null,\n "cost": null,\n "direction": "inbound",\n "encoding": "GSM-7",\n "errors": [],\n "from": {\n "carrier": "Verizon",\n "line_type": "Wireless",\n "phone_number": "+111111111"\n },\n "id": "e8e0d1e3-dce3-",\n "media": [],\n "messaging_profile_id": "400176",\n "organization_id": "717d556f-ba4f-",\n "parts": 1,\n "received_at": "2020-1",\n "record_type": "message",\n "sent_at": null,\n "tags": [],\n "text": "Hi ",\n "to": [\n {\n "carrier": "carr",\n "line_type": "Wireless",\n "phone_number": "+111111111"\n}\n]\n}}}'''
```

It prints as:

```
>>> print(t)
{
 "data": {
 "event_type": "message.received",
 "id": "819",
 "occurred_at": "2020-10",
 "payload": {
 "cc": [],
 "completed_at": null,
 "cost": null,
 "direction": "inbound",
 "encoding": "GSM-7",
 "errors": [],
...
```

To obtain the expected *representation* you should:

1. load it into a Python object: `js = json.loads(t)`
2. dump it back into a string with 2 as indentation: `t2 = json.dumps(js)`

   `t2` actually looks like `'{\n  "data": {\n    "event_type": "message.received",\n    "id": "819",\n    "occurred_at": "2020-10",\n    "payload": {\n      "cc": [],\n      "completed_at": null,\n      "cost": null,\n ...`
3. print it:

   ```
    >>> print(t2)
    {
      "data": {
        "event_type": "message.received",
        "id": "819",
        "occurred_at": "2020-10",
        "payload": {
          "cc": [],
          "completed_at": null,
          "cost": null,
          "direction": "inbound",
          "encoding": "GSM-7",
          "errors": [],
          "from": {
            "carrier": "Verizon",
            "line_type": "Wireless",
    ...
   ```

A one liner could be:

```
print(json.dumps(json.loads(t), indent=2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first load it as a Python dictionary with:

```
import json

myDict = json.loads(jsonString)
```

And then, convert it back to a minimized/indented JSON string:

```
minimizedJSON = json.dumps(myDict)
indentedJSON = json.dumps(myDict, indent = <# of spaces>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this is done through [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which will take your string and parse it into a **python dictionary**:

```
import ast

# replace with full string of yours
s='{\n "data": {\n "event_type": "message.received",\n "id": "819"\n}\n}'

result = ast.literal_eval(s)

print(type(result), result)
```